# Symfony2 Use default locale in routing (one URL for one language)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, translation, locale

I am currently developing a website with Symfony2 and I need to translate it. With tools provided by Symfony2 it’s very easy. But I encounter a problem:

I would like to have specific URL (with prefix) to a language (ie, one URL, a single language), but with a default language. Concretely:

Assume that the default language is English, so

- `http://example.com/fr/hello` display the page in French
- `http://example.com/it/hello` display the page in Italian
- `http://example.com/en/hello` redirect to `http://example.com/hello` (because en is the default language)
- `http://example.com/hello` display of course the page in English (default language)

I naively try to configure my routing like this:

```
#routing.yml
_welcome:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/hello
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Welcome:hello, _locale: en}
```

But that’s don’t work (`http://example.com/en/hello` just display the page in English and `http://example.com/hello` return 404 error).

It’s possible, of course, to create two routes each time, but it is very tedious. So I’m looking for a clean solution.

Incidentally, I noticed that the behavior I was looking for with URL was exactly the one adopted by the official documentation of Symfony2:

`http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/translation.html` display French traduction

`http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/book/translation.html` display Italian traduction

`http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/book/translation.html` redirect to `http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html` (which display the page in English)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install [JMSI18nBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) and apply the strategy `prefix_except_default`.

The bundle will take care of creating the routes for you.

**configuration:**

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [de, en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Further information can be found in the bundle's [documentation](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle).

Comment: This solution responds only partially to my problem, `http://example.com/hello` display well the page in English, but `http://example.com/en/hello`should redirect me to the same page without prefix but return a 404 error…

Comment: create a [`kernel.request`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) listener that performs the redirect/ strips away the `{_locale}` part of the url in case of the default locale -> puzzle solved. I'm sure you'll figure out that one on your own ... and if you're stuck ... ask a new question :)

Comment: is there a solution to this for symfony 3?