# translation in symfony does not work

Tags: php, translation, symfony

Iam trying to get the translation in Symfony3 to work.

'1. I have already set the locale via route, and `$request->getLocale()` returns "en" or "de".

'2. `php bin/console debug:translation de AppBundle` works also

'3. I also have this file and content:

```
#AppBundle/Resources/translations/messages.de.yml
form.name: Name
form.description: Kurzbeschreibung
```

'4. translation ist activated in config.yml

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["de"] }
```

but still, something like `$this->get('translator')->trans('form.description')` only returns "form.description"

so in twig, `{{ 'form.description'|trans }}` does not work

---

It suddenly worked now (after rebooting?), it seems to have been some kind of cache problem, or the translation has to be created first? But how? I found that there is a console command "translation:update", but couldnt find any documentation about, or what other commands might be there.

However, I added a new translation to my messages.yml, then did translation:update and even cache:clear. But now the new translation (`form.content:Inhalt`) is returned as `__form.content`. what the hell?

ok, also solved this, there was a messages.yml created in app/ressources/translation  that had higher priority than my file in the bundle. So thats what the update command does, where can I find informations about that?

There is nothing mentioned in https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html or https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html

Comment: Translation does work in symfony, I do it in my projects all the time.  In fact, I created a solution that will automatically set the locale based on the url.  I have an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711082/symfony-3-redirect-all-routes-to-current-locale-version), let me know if this helps!

Comment: A dumb question perhaps, but have you actually enabled the translator service in your configuration? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#configuration

Comment: yes I did, I updated the question (4.) its ok to ask dumb questions, it might be a dump problem :)

Comment: ok now it works, mh, seems to have been a cache problem, didnt change anything. But there shouldnt be cache problems when iam working in dev, should there? How can I avoid further problems like this?