# Redirect route to language prefix in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Since version 4.1, Symfony now handles multilingual routing without the need of an external plugin (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing). I've translated my routes with success and all works fine except that when accessing the root url ("/"), Symfony renders a 404 error instead of redirecting to a language folder such as "/en/".

I've done some research but most of what i've found is very outdated (mostly Symfony 2). Also ran into this [Symfony 3 Redirect All Routes To Current Locale Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711082/symfony-3-redirect-all-routes-to-current-locale-version) but it seems like an incredibly tedious solution to such a simple problem.

Ideally, i'd also like to redirect the url "/admin" to "/en/admin", but if i can't achieve it i can live with that.

Here's my routes/annotations.yaml file:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        fr: '/fr'
        en: '/en'
        de: '/de'
```

My translations .yaml file:

```
framework:
#default_locale: '%locale%'
default_locale: 'en'
translator:
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
    fallbacks:
        - 'en'
```

Home route configuration:

```
@Route("/", name="home")
```

Comment: What are the `@Route` annotations for your homepage controller and action method?

Comment: Updated with home controller route configuration.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a route matching `/`, probably because all your routes are prefixed with a language code.

You can debug this using the command line tool:

```
php bin/console router:match "/"
```

If it's successful it should return something like this:

```
 [OK] Route "homepage" matches


+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                                                     |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | homepage                                                                                  |
| Path         | /                                                                                         |
| Path Regex   | #^/$#sD                                                                                   |
| Host         | ANY                                                                                       |
| Host Regex   |                                                                                           |
| Scheme       | ANY                                                                                       |
| Method       | GET                                                                                       |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                                                 |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                                           |
| Defaults     | _controller: App\Controller\HomeController::index                                         |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler                                   |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If it is not successful there are multiple options. You could create a listener for the "/" route that tries to determine the proper locale and then redirects to the correct one or just always redirect to your "primary" language, e.g. using a route like this:

```
homepage:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
    defaults:
        path: /en
        permanent: true
```

**edit for clarification:**

Your routes/annotation.yaml could then look like this:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        fr: '/fr'
        en: '/en'
        de: '/de'

home_fallback:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
    defaults:
        path: /en
        permanent: true
```

Comment: The problem is that all my routes are prefixed, i don't think i can actually match "/" without a language prefix.

Comment: Well you can just add this new route to your `config/routes.yaml`. The `defaults.path: /en` will ensure it redirects to that route or do you mean that the actual route also has additional parameters? In that case, if you can maybe show the definition of the route you want to redirect to we can try to devise an EventListener that will perform a more elaborate redirect.